# What is the type VoidTaskResult as it relates to async methods?

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection, asynchronous

I've been using async (and .Net 4.5 really) for the first time recently, and I've come across something that has me stumped. There isn't much information about the `VoidTaskResult` class that I can find on the Net so I came here to see if anyone has any ideas about what is going on.

My code is something like the following. Obviously, this is much simplified. The basic idea is to call plugin methods, which are asynchronous. If they return `Task`, then there is no return value from the async call. If they return `Task<>`, then there is. We don't know in advance which type they are, so the idea is to look at the type of the result using reflection (`IsGenericType` is true if the type is `Type<>`) and get the value using a dynamic type.

In my real code, I am calling the plugin method via reflection. I don't think this should make a difference to the behaviour I am seeing.

```
// plugin method
public Task yada()
{
 // stuff
}

public async void doYada()
{
  Task task = yada();
  await task;

  if (task.GetType().IsGenericType)
  {
    dynamic dynTask = task;
    object result = dynTask.Result;
    // do something with result
  }
}
```

This works good for the plugin method shown above. `IsGenericType` is false (as expected).

However if you change the declaration of the plugin method ever so slightly, `IsGenericType` now returns true and stuff breaks:

```
public async Task yada()
{
 // stuff
}
```

When you do this, the following exception is thrown on the line `object result = dynTask.Result;`:

[image: RuntimeBinderException]

If you dig into the task object, it actually appears to be `Type<VoidTaskResult>`. `VoidTaskResult` is a private type in the Threading name space with almost nothing in it.

[image: VoidTaskResult task]

I tried changing my calling code:

```
public async void doYada()
{
  Task task = yada();
  await task;

  if (task.GetType().IsGenericType)
  {
    object result = task.GetType().GetProperty("Result").GetMethod.Invoke(task, new object[] { });
    // do something with result
  }
}
```

This "succeeds" in the sense that it no longer throws, but now result is of the type `VoidTaskResult` which I cannot sensibly do anything with.

I should add that I'm having a hard time even formulating a real question for all this. Maybe my real question is something like "What is `VoidTaskResult`?", or "Why does this weird thing happen when I call an async method dynamically?" or possibly even "How do you call  plugin methods that are optionally asynchronous?" In any case, I am putting this out there in the hope that one of the gurus will be able to shed some light.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is due to the way the class hierarchy around tasks (and particularly task completion sources) is designed.

First off, `Task<T>` derives from `Task`. I assume you're already familiar with that.

Furthermore, you can create types of `Task` or `Task<T>` for tasks that execute code. E.g., if your first example was returning `Task.Run` or whatnot, then that would be returning an actual `Task` object.

The problem comes in when you consider how `TaskCompletionSource<T>` interacts with the task hierarchy. `TaskCompletionSource<T>` is used to create tasks that don't execute code, but rather act as a notification that some operation has completed. E.g., timeouts, I/O wrappers, or `async` methods.

There is no non-generic `TaskCompletionSource` type, so if you want to have notification like this without a return value (e.g., timeouts or `async Task` methods), then you have to create a `TaskCompletionSource<T>` for some `T` and return the `Task<T>`. The `async` team had to choose a `T` for `async Task` methods, so they created the type `VoidTaskResult`.

Normally this is not a problem. Since `Task<T>` derives from `Task`, the value is converted to `Task` and everyone is happy (in the static world). However, every task created by `TaskCompletionSource<T>` is actually of type `Task<T>`, not `Task`, and you see this with reflection/dynamic code.

The end result is that you have to treat `Task<VoidTaskResult>` just like it was `Task`. However, `VoidTaskResult` is an implementation detail; it may change in the future.

So, I recommend that you actually base your logic on the (declared) return type of `yada`, not the (actual) return value. This more closely mimics what the compiler does.

```
Task task = (Task)yadaMethod.Invoke(...);
await task;

if (yadaMethod.ReturnType.IsGenericType)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Why did the async team introduce VoidTaskResult instead of just introducing a non-generic TaskCompletionSource?

Comment: @Puppy: I suspect because it was a lot less work. Writing a nongeneric `TaskCompletionSource` is not too hard, but any public API has to go through a bunch of other "gates" before it can be released. Security reviews, etc, etc.

Comment: The explanation makes sense. But from a practical standpoint, how can you determine at runtime the difference between a `Task` that has no result and one that does? I.e. since `Task<VoidTaskResult>` is used even for tasks that have no result, and since `VoidTaskResult` is not public, it seems that the only way to check is to compare the `Task<T>` type parameter name. Which I guess is technically okay, but it seems un-C#-like to have to specify a type name as a string in code like that.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: This kind of runtime code is un-C#-like, for sure. Because it's something the compiler never needs to worry about; it always uses the declared type. I'm curious to hear your scenario; there may be a better solution.

Comment: Not my scenario per se. I ran into this after reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59080219). I put together an answer that I think addresses the specific request in the question, but the need to rely on the _text_ name of a non-public type bugs me (it would be bad enough if I could've used the `typeof` operator, but having to compare the name as text is especially annoying to me).